# How to write this yii2 rule?

Tags: php, validation, yii2, rules

Currently I have this rule which checks for existing ID in Employee table.

```
[['manager_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => false, 'targetClass' => Employee::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['manager_id' => 'id']]
```

Is there any way I can modify this rule to also accept 0 as valid value although I dont have Employee with ID = 0 in this table?

Comment: You can create a custom rule, which will allow you to perform this task.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like issue with `targetAttribute` value. Could you try just set `'targetAttribute' => 'id'`

```
[['manager_id'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => false, 'targetClass' => Employee::className(), 'targetAttribute' => 'id']
```